# Workflow limits and alternate approach

Tags: limits, time-dependent-workflow, alternatives

I noticed that workflow I scheduled runs only about 500 records at a time and it runs consecutively every hour. Is this because of org limit? I am worried as I have 20K records to execute and it is going to take 40 hours to complete this!

**Is there alternative option to implement in place of workflows?** 
This workflow is a time dependent workflow which runs 6 hours after a field is set to TRUE through trigger.

Comment: Why are the all updates at the same/similar time - did you dataload them in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an hourly limit of 500 for enterprise edition and 1000 from unlimited.
You are correct in saying that it will eventually catch up:

> Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can
>   execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its
>   Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time
>   triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition
>   organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and
>   6:00 PM.

Now as for alternatives it depends on your use case - it looks like you dataloaded them in for all the updates to be at/around the same time. An alternative would be a schedulable batch class which you could set up to run multiple times a day.

**Time based workflow FAQ:**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1

**Timed based workflow considerations:**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0